# how to block javascript function from invoking till completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to block click events to invoke function till this function completed , i have written this function :

```js
$(".cycle-next").on('click',function(){
  var contWidth = $(".container").width(); 
  var finalWidth = ((contWidth*.25)*-1)+(parseInt($(".inner").css("left"))); 
  var contWidthC = contWidth*-1;
    
   if(finalWidth === contWidthC){
      $(".inner").animate({left:"0"},200,function(){
                     
                    });
             }
  
});
```

here once we click on  (cycle-next) element , the function start executing , suppose the controller in the middle of function , at this point user again click on the element for second time , again the controller start from the beginning of function without completing , How to make second click wait until completing ?

Comment: How about adding a loading icon till web service returns data?

Comment: Simplest way to do this is to wrap the function within another function, making a closure, then add a flag within the closure scope that will get modified in a `true/false` manner to allow the function execution or not. If you want a fiddle, say so.

Comment: @Dellirium - or use `element.dataset`

Comment: Could you show a working example of the problem? Given your current code sample the behaviour should already do what you need. Clicking multiple times will not reset the element to its original position

Comment: Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/c8n86gsL/  @JaromandaX revolutionary!

Comment: @Dellirium - that simply ignores clicks while "things are happening" - *wait until completing*, at least to me, suggests that subsequent clicks still get processed, just after the previous "click animation" finishes - I could be wrong though :p

Comment: They don't since the function returns if flag is dropped. But the comment referencing you was just a "thanks" for telling us about dataset, its news to me. Could avoid the whole wrapper in that case. The example is meant for the OP, im sure you wouldn't struggle with it.

Comment: s'all good @Dellirium

Answer (score 0):

Using `.promise()` and `$.when()` (and an IIFE) should do the trick

```
;(function() {
    var p = $.when(); // initial "promise" to get things moving on the first click
    $(".cycle-next").on('click',function(){
        p = p.then(function() { // chain the promise
            var $inner = $('.inner');
            var contWidth = $(".container").width(); 
            var finalWidth = ((contWidth * .25) * -1) + parseInt($(".inner").css("left")); 
            var contWidthC = contWidth * -1;

            if (finalWidth === contWidthC) {
                return $inner.animate({ left: "0" }, 200, function() {
                    // put logic to execute when the animation ends here, or remove this if not needed
                }).promise(); // returns a promise that presumably resolves when animation completes
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

To be honest though, re-reading the question,

1. you start by saying you want to block subsequent clicks,
2. you end the question saying that subsequent clicks should wait for the animation to complete

the two are mutually exclusive

This answer will, more or less, queue the click events to be processed sequentially once the previous animation completes

Comment: how can i queue the click events to be processed sequentially  ??

Comment: the last sentence in the answer tells you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a flag. I chose a css class so you can style the buttonwhile it is disabled.

if `.cycle-next` is a form-element, you could go with `.prop("disabled", true)`, or with a dataset-value `.data("disabled", true)`

```
$(".cycle-next").on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass("disabled")) return false;

    var contWidth = $(".container").width(); 
    var finalWidth = ((contWidth*.25)*-1)+(parseInt($(".inner").css("left"))); 
    var contWidthC = contWidth*-1;

    if(finalWidth === contWidthC){
        $this.addClass("disabled");
        $(".inner").animate({left:"0"},200,function(){
            $this.removeClass("disabled");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use an AJAX call on click to disable the button and on success of the AJAX call enable the button again. This is a consistent solution

Comment: there's an AJAX call? must be in the code the OP didn't post, or mention at all

Comment: did not mention ,does not mean he can not use it

Comment: what? use an AJAX call, just for the fun of it?

Comment: What would making an AJAX request possibly have to do with a queued animation ending? This is a very odd answer